# Shortest Path Algorithms: Dynamic Programming vs Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, dijkstra

Running shortest path algorithm on a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) via dynamic programming which uses *memoization* has a runtime complexity of `O(V + E)` which can be verified using the following equation:

```
d(s,v) = min{ d(s,u) + w(u,v) }, over all vertices u->v
```

Now, Dijkstra's algorithm also requires the graph to be directed. And the algorithm has a runtime complexity of `O(E + V.log(V))` using min priority queues and this is clearly slower than the memoized version of DP.

According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm):

> This is asymptotically the fastest known single-source shortest-path algorithm for arbitrary directed graphs with unbounded non-negative weights.

Am I missing something here? I am just not able to digest the contradiction here..

Comment: From what I gather the dp algorithm you describe is Bellman Ford which is slower than Dijkstra's but can handle arbitrary graphs with no negative cycles. The runtime is O(VE). Please verify you haven't muddled up your analysis.

Comment: No, the analysis of the DP algorithm is correct if you consider the memoization bit. Since we have only O(E) subproblems, the overall complexity will turn out to be O(E+V).

Comment: You need to run your algorithm O(V) times in the worst case each with worst case O(E) sub problems hence the runtime of O(VE). Please see the analysis of bellman ford on Wikipedia to see what I mean.

Comment: @ldog: You are barking up the wrong algorithm :D He's talking about [Topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), not about [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dijkstra's Algorithm is not restricted to DAGs; it can be run on any graphs with no negative path weights, cyclic or otherwise. Topological sorting, that you most likely are referring to, fails the "arbitrary" clause of your Wiki quote.

Comment: Can you please explain what is meant by failing the "arbitrary" clause in case of DP solution?

Comment: Dijkstra's can solve cyclic graphs. Topological sorting can't. It's like coming across the sentence "Formula 1 are fastest land-based vehicles", then wondering if that's correct because Concorde goes faster. Not land-based, doesn't matter. Same here: Dijkstra's is the fastest if you allow cyclic graphs; the fact that Topological sorting can find shortest path faster doesn't matter because it only does it on DAGs.

Comment: Thanks, got the difference!

Answer (score 2):

In your dynamic programming, I do not think it is a correct formula, because it is based on the fact that d(s, u) is already the shortest path between s, u. But you can not confirm that. To confirm that you should get the "shortest vertices" step by step using greedy method, so that is what Dijkstra's algorithm do.

And for Dynamic programming, the Floyd–Warshall algorithm is a typical way, you can reference it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm. Think it carefully!

Comment: In fact, now as I see it, the DP solution would also return me the shortest paths to all other vertices from a single source vertex in the given time bound only..